# Suggestion based on user's search

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have this problem: in my website the user writes in an input bar the name of an ArtWork. Then, usign the Google APIs, I give him the title, the image as well as other useful details.

But on my website I've also uploaded e-books containing useful information to use during the search. My question is: is there a way that makes the system suggest the user the most useful e-books based on his search (for ex.: if I type in Andy Warhol, I would only like to see e-books that talk about Modern Art and not those that talk about Greek or Roman art).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple-ish version of how to do that. You will have to insert into a database your ebook name and what other info you want about them.

Then you will have a query which searches like this:

```
$search = 'your search term';
$query = 'select * from ebook_data e where e.name like "%'.$search.'%";
```

And then run that query with mysqli http://php.net/mysqli

Top websites usually have a neural network for recommendations, which are useful to predict with high accuracy what your visitor may like.